# putting text on image seems to make the links in nav disappear (float relative clash?)

Tags: html, css

I'm new at this and so this might be really embarrassing...bang head on table embarrassing... but here goes....
I have a nav bar and then under (not behind) I have an image. The nav works fine. img fine. Until, I add absolutely positioned text on top of the relatively positioned image and then the links on my nav no longer work except in IE ha ha.... when I remove the line position: relative in the box div my nav links work.... I think its some clash between a float and relative...seems really basic....
helllllpppp.... Is there a way to do this? :( here is some code.

```
         <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="a.html" title="a page">a</a></li>
            <li><a href="b.html" title="b page">b</a></li>
            <li><a href="c.html" title="c page">c</a></li>
            <li><a href="d.html" title="d page">d</a></li>
            <li><a href="e.html" title="e page">e</a></li>
            <li><a href="f.html" title="f page">f</a></li>
            <li><a href="g.html" title="g page">g</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="box">
            <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="image">
            <p id="box2">
                text text text text text
            </p>
        </div>
       css:

              #allcontent {
            width:  910px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;}
              #nav {
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0; } 
              #nav li {
            float: left; }
              #nav li a {
            display:block;  
            width:130px; 
            background-color: black;}
              #nav li a:hover{
            background-color: red;}
              #box {
                position: relative;}
              #box2 {
                position: absolute;
                top: 300px;
                left: 0;
            color: blue;
            background: black;
            width: 250px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the box is after the nav in the mark-up using floats will take that element of the the natural flow of the document and elements can become  stacked on top of one another. The problem here is that the box element is actually on top of the nav so it cannot be clicked as your actually clicking on the box div not the nav.

Changing your class to the following will solve your issue.

```
#box {
       position: relative;
       z-index: -1;
}
```

More information about z-index can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp